# How to save the post variables with more than 1000 post variables?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to save the post variables which contains more than 1000 post variables. I tried to save using submit button but it is not saving more than 1000 post variables due to php.ini restriction max_input_vars default set to 1000. I don't want to edit the php.ini file but still want to submit those post variables. I know it's not possible using the default form submit. Is there any way like jquery way to save those in database.

Actually, I tried using jquery ajax method but still, it's reproducing the same error.

```
$("#single-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var table_data = $(this).serialize();
    // console.log(table_data);
    table_action = 'backend_table_data_save';
    $.ajax({
        url : ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action  : 'backend_ajax',
            _action : table_action,
            table_data: table_data,
            },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.backend-ajax-loader-div').show();
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('.backend-ajax-loader-div').hide();
        },
        success: function (response){
            $('.ajax-loaded-div').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

But when I print table_data post variables it's returning only 1000 post variables.

```
parse_str( $_POST['table_data'], $post_variables ); 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($post_variables); 
echo "</pre>"; 
die();
```

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: There is no difference in a "normal" post and a jquery post for the server. You could try to split up your post in chunks of 1000 in jquery and post one chunk at a time

Comment: try to combine inputs like for name age address ,, Use user_info=name_here&age_here etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize ini_set('max_input_vars', 1000) in your code if you don't want to edit php.ini. Else you need to split the post array in client side into chunks and fire ajax requests separately.

Answer (score 0):

If your data are similar you can post them as array if your data are more complex you can create a json object update it with data on submit and then post the stringify object by putting it in a hidden input field (this approach requires a bit of javascript but not somethign too difficult), in the previus cases you are going to have one variable. Can you please provide more information (html form) about what you want to post?